# How to merge multiple hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash

Right now, I'm merging two hashes like this:

```
department_hash  = self.parse_department html
super_saver_hash = self.parse_super_saver html

final_hash = department_hash.merge(super_saver_hash)
```

Output:

> {:department=>{"Pet Supplies"=>{"Birds"=>16281, "Cats"=>245512,
>   "Dogs"=>513926, "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>46811, "Horses"=>14805,
>   "Insects"=>364, "Reptiles & Amphibians"=>5816, "Small
>   Animals"=>19769}}, :super_saver=>{"Free Super Saver
>   Shipping"=>126649}}

But now I want to merge more in the future. For example:

```
department_hash  = self.parse_department html
super_saver_hash = self.parse_super_saver html
categories_hash  = self.parse_categories html
```

How to merge multiple hashes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do below way using [**`Enumerable#inject`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
h = {}
arr = [{:a=>"b"},{"c" => 2},{:a=>4,"c"=>"Hi"}]
arr.inject(h,:update)
# => {:a=>4, "c"=>"Hi"}
arr.inject(:update)
# => {:a=>4, "c"=>"Hi"}
```

Answer (score 25):

How about:

```
[department_hash, super_saver_hash, categories_hash].reduce &:merge
```

Comment: why `&` ? `[department_hash, super_saver_hash, categories_hash].reduce(:merge)` is fine...

Comment: That's just my preference. I think the `&` informs something and is worthwhile.

Comment: @Babai because this style is consistent with e.g. `Enumerable#map` which requires a proc.

Answer (score 16):

You can just call `merge` again:

```
h1 = {foo: :bar}
h2 = {baz: :qux}
h3 = {quux: :garply}

h1.merge(h2).merge(h3)
#=> {:foo=>:bar, :baz=>:qux, :quux=>:garply}
```

Comment: I think the point is how would it be possible to do this with a single call. `h1.merge(h2, h3)` Obviously this does not actually work, but such behavior could be useful.

Comment: this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out how to merge multi-nested hashes after going through this Question and its Answers. It turned out I was iterating through the collections of hashes incorrectly, causing all kinds of problems with `null` values.

This [sample](https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/784cd7216549972bf80ade8bd0db7fd1) command-line app shows how to merge multiple hashes with a combination of `store` and `merge!`, depending on whether or not they were top-level hash keys. It uses command-line args with a few known key name for categorization purposes.

Full code from the Gist URL is provided below as a courtesy:

```
# Ruby - A nested hash example
# Load each pair of args on the command-line as a key-value pair
# For example from CMD.exe:
# call ruby.exe ruby_nested_hash_example.rb Age 30 Name Mary Fav_Hobby Ataraxia Fav_Number 42
# Output would be:
    # {
      # "data_info": {
        # "types": {
          # "nums": {
            # "Age": 30,
            # "Fav_Number": 42
          # },
          # "strings": {
            # "Name": "Mary",
            # "Fav_Hobby": "Ataraxia"
          # }
        # },
        # "data_id": "13435436457"
      # }
    # }


if (ARGV.count % 2 != 0) || (ARGV.count < 2)
    STDERR.puts "You must provide an even amount of command-line args to make key-value pairs.\n"
    abort
end
require 'json'


cmd_hashes = {}
nums = {}
strings = {}
types = {}
#FYI `tl` == top-level
all_tl_keys = {}
data_info = {}
data_id = {:data_id => "13435436457"}


_key = ""
_value = ""
element = 0
ARGV.each do |i|
    if element % 2 == 0
        _key=i
    else
        if (i.to_i!=0) && (i!=0)
            _value=i.to_i
        else
            _value=i
        end
    end
    if (_key != "") && (_value != "")
        cmd_hashes.store(_key, _value)
        _key = ""
        _value = ""
    end
    element+=1
end


cmd_hashes.each do |key, value|
    if value.is_a? Numeric
        nums.store(key, value)
    else
        strings.store(key, value)
    end
end


if nums.size        > 0;    types.merge!(:nums => nums)                 end
if strings.size     > 0;    types.merge!(:strings => strings)           end
if types.size       > 0;    all_tl_keys.merge!(:types => types)         end
if data_id.size     > 0;    all_tl_keys.merge!(data_id)                 end
if all_tl_keys.size > 0;    data_info.merge!(:data_info => all_tl_keys) end


if data_info.size   > 0;    puts JSON.pretty_generate(data_info)        end
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are having `arr = [{x: 10},{y: 20},{z: 30}]`
then do

```
arr.reduce(:merge)
```